# HTML href not finding resource in project

Tags: angularjs, html, gulp, angular-ui-router

I've been trying to learn angularJS, specifically 1.5 using components. My IDE is c9 so the server uses port: process.env.PORT which when I start will show the project at https://projectName-username.c9users.io (with angular-ui-router it has '/#!' on the end). This ide doesn't seem to compile es6 without using something like gulp. So I copy pasted much of the gulp code from the tutorial into my own project so that I could continue using the es6 syntax to build my own project.Everything is working pretty well except I am trying to link bootstrap 4 and my own css files from inside the project rather than a cdn and I can't seem to get the file path correct. When running the gulp file it says serving files from ./build so I tried writing the path from there but it has 404 on the resource.The closest I've come to was no errors thrown trying `<link rel="stylesheet" src="#!/src/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">` but checking the network it says it's loading https://billardsWebsite-rawlejuglal.c9users.io/ with type stylesheet but nothing is actually there.  Below is my file structure, the index.html file  and then the gulpfile. If anyone can enlighten me on how to structure my links to find these resources I would appreciate it.

```
billardsWebsite
  -.c9
  -.git
  -build
    -index.html
    -main.js
  -node_modules
  -src
    -bower_components
      -boostrap
        -dist
          -css
            -bootstrap.min.css
    -js
    -css
      -styles.css
    -index.html
  -.bowerrc
  -.bower.json
  -gulpfile.js
  -package.json
  -Procfile
```

Index.html (src/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#!/src/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var notify        = require('gulp-notify');
var source        = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify    = require('browserify');
var babelify      = require('babelify');
var ngAnnotate    = require('browserify-ngannotate');
var browserSync   = require('browser-sync').create();
var rename        = require('gulp-rename');
var templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');
var uglify        = require('gulp-uglify');
var merge         = require('merge-stream');

// Where our files are located
var jsFiles   = "src/js/**/*.js";
var viewFiles = "src/js/**/*.html";

var interceptErrors = function(error) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  // Send error to notification center with gulp-notify
  notify.onError({
    title: 'Compile Error',
    message: '<%= error.message %>'
  }).apply(this, args);

  // Keep gulp from hanging on this task
  this.emit('end');
};


gulp.task('browserify', ['views'], function() {
  return browserify('./src/js/app.js')
      .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015"]})
      .transform(ngAnnotate)
      .bundle()
      .on('error', interceptErrors)
      //Pass desired output filename to vinyl-source-stream
      .pipe(source('main.js'))
      // Start piping stream to tasks!
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src("src/index.html")
      .on('error', interceptErrors)
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('views', function() {
  return gulp.src(viewFiles)
      .pipe(templateCache({
        standalone: true
      }))
      .on('error', interceptErrors)
      .pipe(rename("app.templates.js"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/js/config/'));
});

// This task is used for building production ready
// minified JS/CSS files into the dist/ folder
gulp.task('build', ['html', 'browserify'], function() {
  var html = gulp.src("build/index.html")
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));

  var js = gulp.src("build/main.js")
           .pipe(uglify())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));

  return merge(html,js);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'browserify'], function() {

  browserSync.init(['./build/**/**.**'], {
    server: "./build",
    port: process.env.PORT || '3000',
    notify: false,
    ui: {
      port: 3001
    }
  });

  gulp.watch("src/index.html", ['html']);
  gulp.watch(viewFiles, ['views']);
  gulp.watch(jsFiles, ['browserify']);
});
```

Comment: Can you make sure if the stylesheets css are copying to your build folder? How do you serve your app? You shouldn't use the `#!/` syntax to import libraries since it is a prefix that the angular router uses. In your example tree you don't mention the css files in the build folder. Could that be the error?

Comment: the gulpfile I don't really know anything about. I  copy pasted it because the tutorial  started the server with the gulp file. I just type gulp in the CLI and it makes the build folder. I can take out the '#!' I was just trying things to get to the bootstrap file(without I get 404 error). Everything in bower_components and css folders I added because originally the tutorial linked to external stylesheet and bootstrap cdn and I wanted to create my own styles and practice with bootstrap 4. Will the gulp file need another task to put the css and bower_components in the build folder?

Comment: basically yes, because it will need to output your processed styles (in case you use a css preprocessor such as SASS, LESS, etc.) or at least copy the css to your build.

Comment: Ok, thanks. guess I better go research some gulp.